# Persons protection: residual-current circuit breaker for DC?

Tags: safety, circuit-breaker

I'm currently reviewing the schematics of the power supply of a robot prototype.
The 380 V AC (3 phase) is converted (isolated converter) into 320 V DC (up to 20 A).

There are only 3 wires going to the robot : the + and - of the 320 V DC, and earth (connected to the earth of the 380 V AC).

Protection wise, we have ground fault circuits breakers (and resistance to earth measurements) BEFORE the converter. The converter itself has basic protections (over current, over voltage, over power, over temperature). If the converter is cut/powered-off, it only guarantees that output voltage goes bellow 60 V after 10 s. We added a magneto-thermic DC circuit-breaker on the output.

So I would guess, we should be pretty safe for shorts.

However, I'm not sure if we got enough protection in case someone touches a wire.
One the one hand, the converter is isolated, so the voltages are floating. This should provide protection. However, is it reasonable to rely on the fact that - and earth are not connected?

To make things even worse, in future, we want to supply GND, +320 V and earth to client tools. So we have no way to make sure that in the client tool earth and GND are not connected.

Do residual-current circuit breakers exist for DC? And are they useful/needed?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7PQ7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Sandro, is the Q and A done now; you know the drill.

Comment: For now, I still haven't a fully satisfactory solution. We have an earth leak detection in addition to the schematics, but it is slow to react (about 5 seconds when connecting to earth through a 1k to 500k resistor), and it seems to prevent the voltage from being really floating : when one wire (either GND or +320V DC) to earth through a 1k resistor to "simulate" a human, we measure about 8mA for 10ms : nothing too dangerous according to the test, but a test isn't a proof that it is the worse case, so I'm still not really satisfied

Comment: What are you not satisfied about Sandro? It's unclear where your dissatisfaction lies. I guess, based on no upvotes to either answer (as per [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)) you haven't found help in the answers. If this is true then it's possible that your question might have been misleading somehow and caused answers to run off-track but, without feedback, this is impossible to judge from my standpoint.

Comment: When saying that I'm not really satisfied, I was referring to our circuit as currently build : several seconds before protection on earth leak (so plenty of time to touch the second conductor), and even when just touching one conductor, there is still a (small) shock, which was "just" measured, and not proven to be a worst case value.

Comment: For the answers, by re-reading it now after doing the tests, I would say yours is useful, even when first reading it I wasn't able to turn it into some concrete action (but it's probably due to the fact that I'm not very used to work on earth connected / "high" voltage circuits : until now, nearly all I've done was bellow 30V)

Comment: Sandro, I see you have upvoted my answer but, if both answers are equally useful then, both should be upvoted to be fair. If neither were useful then neither should be upvoted. Also, I don't see you can have an earth current breaker given that the output is floating but, maybe you have moved on schematically from your question.

Comment: There is still no current breaker, just an earth isolation measurement unit that can cut the supply of the AC/DC converter (it was already in place, but I hadn't analyzed it before). Your answer wasn't enjoyable ("nothing I can do") but useful, so it deserves its upvote. For the other answer, the part on type B breakers is wrong as far as I understood, the part about thinking if I need a differential breaker is useful : as I can't upvote and down vote at the same time, I decided just not to vote on that question

Comment: Sandro, since you made the above schematic you have implemented a system (described in your newer question) that forces a small signal (with respect to earth) onto the DC output wires and, that system can be used to detect someone touching either of the 320 volt DC outputs. Given that that is the case (not shown in the question above) and, your question above was about the usefulness of a residual current breaker, it seems to me that my answer is correct and that this Q and A session should be closed.

Comment: Truth be told, the Bender (earth leak detection) was already in place on the current prototype for a long type, but I hadn't considered it as useful for people protection (it was mainly added to detect water ingress or damaged cables on our ROV). But yes, I think we can close this Q&A

Comment: I'm thinking that the Bender "idea" could work if altered a bit. Can't say it can be modified but, if 320 volts ground was "lifted" by 5 volts above earth via (say) a 1 Mohm resistor then, if you touched the 320 volts ground terminal, instead of tripping it could give you a buzzer warning based on the detection of 5 uA flow. However, it the 320 volts (plus 5) was detected, the current would be 325 uA and that should immediately trip the supply.

Comment: I'm not sure to get your idea : why do you want that when touching the ground (o the 320V) it just triggers a buzzer instead of cutting everything? Wouldn't it decrease safety instead of improving it? (I don't see either how this could help for the question about the scope if that was the point)

Comment: Well, if someone is using a scope then presumably they are a trained person and the beeper keeps reminding them to be vigilant. Then, if they do come into contact with the positive, it would trip on 325 uA or above. Obviously the trip can't be instant and it's likely that the current could be several mA for several milliseconds @sandro. It's just a possible way forward.

Comment: Indeed, if replacing the Bender by a custom "equivalent" as you describe, it would retain the security from the bender while not triggering (just buzzing) while using the scope.

Comment: Food for thought!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the converter is isolated, so the voltages are floating. This should
> provide protection.*

If someone touches (say) the negative terminal of the DC output they won't receive any warning that they have touched it and, they may continue to remain in contact with that terminal until some point later when they touch the positive 320 volts terminal.

That is the problem scenario you have to overcome in my opinion.

This is why both live and neutral terminals and connections are insulated from a user in an AC appliance. If, in the unlikely situation that the user came in contact with AC neutral (for a sustained period) and also touched live, sure they'd get a shock but, an RCD (residual current device) or GFCI (ground fault circuit interrupter) would likely detect some earth leakage current (or an imbalance current) and disconnect the AC threat.

The problem with your system proposal is that you are anticipating that some people may have access to the power terminals and, there is no bypass earth/ground path to create an imbalance current that could activate a trip device.

> *Do residual-current circuit breakers exist for DC? And are they
> useful/needed?*

A DC residual current device (if available) would only work if the current flow from positive to negative had an additional imbalanced ground/earth content but, because the supply output is floating (intentionally) then, it can't work in my opinion. The imbalance current cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

A Type A residual current breaker will not trip on an DC fault current. In fact, it will **not trip at all anymore** with even a few millimeters of DC current due to saturation of the sensing transformer.

If you want AC and DC differential current circuit breakers you need [type B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device#Type_(types_of_leakage_current_detected)).

You should investigate if you really *need* DC differential fault protection because these units are expensive and are not yet available in RCBO (Combined MCB+RCD) versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like a DC current breaker. I'm not sure that type B is OK for DC applications. From what I understood from the FAQ from Schneider (https://www.se.com/fr/fr/faqs/FA20755/ (sorry, I couldn't find it in English), type B is supposed to break if it detects a DC component on a circuit that is supposed to be pure AC. But is not adapted to DC circuits

Comment: @Sandro I don't know of any standard product that fit that purpose. Maybe Bender has some with a special CT.